Component-wise polynomial function is continuous on arbitrary topological spaces
In context of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, exercise I.3.2.a), I need to argue that the map
$$\varphi:\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^2: t\mapsto (t^2,t^3)$$
is a bijective bicontinuous morphism of $\mathbb{A}^1$ onto the curve given by $y^2=x^3$. I've proven everything except the continunity.
I wonder, whether I can use the fact that $\varphi$ is given by polynomials in order to argue that the function is continuous. I know that would be the case for subsets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, because $\varphi$ is partially differentiable and the partial derivatives are continuous, and this implies that the function is continuous (and even totally differentiable). However, in this example $\mathbb{A}$ is an arbitrary algebraically closed field equipped with the Zariski topology, in particular it is not even a metric space, thus I can not talk about being differentiable in this case at all (Except if I define the formal derivative of polynomials like often done in algebra).
However, I wonder if I can still deduce from the polynomials that the entire function $\varphi$ must be continuous? If not, how can I show that the function $\varphi$ is continuous? Continuity in the other direction is easy because all open subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1$ are finite, thus mapped on finite subsets of $\mathbb{A}^2$, but finite subsets are open there. But in $\mathbb{A}^2$ there are also infinite open subsets, therefore this argument does not work in this direction.
I'd really appreciate any help on this.

FYI, you had some minor typos and had flipped the order of the section and the exercise, so I fixed those for you.

Sure, you can. By lemma I.3.6, if $X$ is any variety and $Y\subset\Bbb A^n$ is an affine variety, a map of sets $\psi:X\to Y$ is a morphism iff $x_i\circ\psi$ is a regular function on $X$ for every coordinate function $x_i$ on $\Bbb A^n$. Since $t\mapsto t^2$ and $t\mapsto t^3$ are regular functions on $\Bbb A^1$ by definition, you win.
Alternatively, you could prove this directly if you knew a bit more about the structure of open sets in a variety: for any affine variety $X$, every open set is the union of principal open sets, i.e. those of the form $D(f)$ for some $f\in k[X]$. After you prove that for $\varphi:Y\to X$, $\varphi^{-1}(D(f))=D(\varphi^*(f))$, you could prove directly that this map is continuous.

Also, let me point out a minor imprecisions here: for continuity in the other direction, you want to use the condition "closed" instead of "open" - the closed sets of $\Bbb A^1$ are the finite sets and the whole space; finite subsets of $\Bbb A^2$ are closed.

Thank you very much for your fast and comprehensible answer! Actually I have used Lemma 3.6 to prove that $\varphi$ is a morphism, but forgot that this implies by definition that it is also continuous. I have just started to study this topic.
